# Unable to identify value of HTML form element using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to implement a message system in my project by using AJAX, but I have got some problems because I am new to AJAX.
The code below is able to send input data from the `MsgMain.php` file to `MsgInsert.php` perfectly. But when I try to get `$_POST['msgSend']` from `MsgMain.php` on `MsgInsert.php` it fails.

**AJAX Code** is on MsgMain.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chatBtn").click(function(){
        $("#msgBtn").val("chat");
    });
    $("#pmBtn").click(function(){
        $("#msgBtn").val("pm");
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("#msgBtn").click(function() {
        var textcontent = $("#msgInput").val();
        var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent;
        if(textcontent=='')
        {
            alert("Enter some text..");
            $("#msgInput").focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "msg/MsgInsert.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: true,
                success: function(response){
                    document.getElementById('content').value='';
                    $("#msgBtn").focus();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

`MsgMain.php` file code just for the HTML form

```
<form action="MsgInsert.php" id="frmBox" name="msgSend" method="POST" onsubmit="return formSubmit();">
    <div class="input-group ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="msgBox" id="msgInput" title="Enter your message" required>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success w3-hover-white w3-hover-text-green" type="submit" id="msgBtn" title="Send your message" value="chat"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i></button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

`MsgInsert.php` file code, which works well when I remove the if statement of `$_POST['msgSend']`

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    header("location: ../index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
if (isset($_POST['content'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['msgSend'])) {
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "msg");
        if (!$conn) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        $content=$_POST['content'];
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `msgpm`(`id`, `msgFrom`, `msgTo`, `msg`) VALUES ('','bob','ram','$content')");
    }
}
?>
```

Sorry if this type of question has already been asked.

Comment: code indentation makes code readable

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry for long code

Comment: long code is quite fine ... but lack of indentation makes the code hard to read - surely you don't write code like that?

Comment: because you only send one post variable $_POST['content']

Comment: @Gaurav But i don't know how to send two variable and get them separately.

Comment: Use this code
 data: {content: textcontent , msgSend: msg},

Comment: @Gaurav Problem solve by using your syntax

Comment: that's cool. upvote comment .

Comment: @Gaurav I don't know how to up vote your comment.

Comment: @Nawaraj , hover on the left side on starting. there you see two option one is upper arrow and flag .Click on the arrow .that's it

Comment: @Gaurav I think my reputation is not enough for voting.

Comment: okay.No problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the `msgSent` attribute, according to this line in your JS:

```
var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent;
```

I can see only the `content` which you will be able to use via `$_POST['content']`.

Try this:

```
var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent + '&msgSent' + '<?php echo $_POST['msgSent']; ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `msgSend` Parameter according to your implementation of `MsgInsert.php` like so:

```
$("#msgBtn").click(function () {
    var textcontent = $("#msgInput").val();

    if (textcontent == '') {
        alert("Enter some text..");
        $("#msgInput").focus();
    }
    else {
        var dataString = 'content=' + textcontent + '&msgSend=1';
        $.ajax({...});
    }
});
```

Always think of [escaping](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) your content via i.e. [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php) when saving user generated content into your database to avoid sql injection!